# build error with SWIG

Tags: python, swig

I am trying to start my journey into building Python extension with SWIG, but I immediately find one error. Probably the solution is very simple, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I would like to wrap a simple C add() function:

```
/* sample.h */
extern int add(int, int);
```

My sample.i file is:

```
// sample.i - Swig interface
%module sample
%{
#include "sample.h"
%}
```

My setup.py file is:

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='sample',
  py_modules=['sample.py'],
  ext_modules=[
  Extension('_sample',
  ['sample_wrap.c'],
  include_dirs = [],
  define_macros = [],
  undef_macros = [],
  library_dirs = [],
  libraries = ['sample']
  )
 ]
)
```

Then I try to get the extension module compiled by running:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But I get an error from linker stating that **sample.lib** is missing.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Did you build sample.lib?

Answer (score 0):

I have **understood** the problem. The library line in sample.I is not needed.
The problem is solved.